# Is there a way to find sequence of instructions?

Tags: ida

I have the following python script to find the "CMP" instruction.

```
find_text(xref.frm, 0, 0, "CMP.*", SEARCH_UP|SEARCH_REGEX)
```

But that returns the first instance of the CMP instruction whereas the one that I want is residing in the lower address.

So I was wondering if there is a way to find a sequence of instruction like

```
find_text(xref.frm, 0, 0, "CMP.*MOV.*CMP.*", SEARCH_UP|SEARCH_REGEX)
```

of return the last result of the search?

(The one above didn't work for me)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
result = find_text(xref.frm, 0, 0, "CMP.*", SEARCH_UP|SEARCH_REGEX)
while result != BADADDR:
    print(hex(result))
    result = find_text(result + get_item_size(result), 0, 0, "CMP.*", SEARCH_UP|SEARCH_REGEX)
```

In addition, you can use `find_binary`, and look for specific bytes of your instrctions, instead of looking for text.